# Service.startActivity(intent) throws null pointer exception

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception

I have a weird problem that I can't solve. I'm trying to open a ListActivity from a Service I made of my own. The ListActivity receives foto paths from the service, which has to been show in a list. This is the code of the service:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast to=Toast.makeText(this, "entrando en servicio", 1000);
    to.show();
    accederFotosFolder();
    crearArrayFotos();      
    Intent i=new Intent(this.getBaseContext(),Lista.class);
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putStringArrayList("imagenes",imagenes);
    i.putExtras(b);
    Toast t=Toast.makeText(this, ""+i, 1000);
    t.show();
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

When I Run this I always have a null pointer Exception.

I checked and nothing is null, not the bundle, not imagenes (which is an `ArrayList<String>` with 2 elements generated by accederFotosFolder()+crearArrayFotos() ). Neither is the intent. If I comment startActivity(i) everything works, so is that line for sure. First thing I thought was that mi ListActivity had something wrong, but it never goes into it's code, It just stops at startActivity(i) line.

Any suggestions? It's driving me mad.

UPDATE

```
 **That's the logcat output**

11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      start service com.example.serviciofotos.Servicio@4166f550 with Intent { cmp=com.example.serviciofotos/.Servicio }: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2518)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)    
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:871)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.example.serviciofotos.Servicio.onStart(Servicio.java:53)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2501)
11-21 19:02:32.214: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION!!!!!

FINALLY!!! ok, there was 2 mistakes.
First one is that my line
      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); is in the wrong place, It have to be just after the declaration of the intent.

Second problem is that i was sending an ArrayList to my ListActivity and triying to receive an String (wrong bundle method). So that's it.

Thank's to everyone who wanted help. Here the right code of the service:

```
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast to=Toast.makeText(this, "entrando en servicio", 1000);
    to.show();
    accederFotosFolder();
    crearArrayFotos();

    Intent i=new Intent(Servicio.this.getBaseContext(),Lista.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putStringArrayList("imagenes",imagenes);
    i.putExtras(b);
    getApplication().startActivity(i);
}
```

And the ListActivity

```
   public class Lista extends ListActivity {
private Bundle recogerDatos=new Bundle();
private ArrayList<String> imagenes;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recogerDatos=this.getIntent().getExtras();

    imagenes=recogerDatos.getStringArrayList("imagenes");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, imagenes);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Current Service Context or `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getBaseContext()` to start ListActivity from service as:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Your_Service_Name.this,Lista.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("imagenes",imagenes);
i.putExtras(b);
Toast t=Toast.makeText(this, ""+i, 1000);
t.show();
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks but not working. I used Servicio.this (that's the name of my Service) and I'm having the same problem

Comment: then post full log cat result when your app is crashing maybe you have some issue in `Lista.class`

Comment: Ok, I posted the logcat, but the program never goes into Lista's code.

Comment: @user1579122 : just add `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);` these to flag with intent when you are starting Activity from service

Comment: I used this, but still with that problem

Comment: @user1579122 : plz post latest logcat

Comment: last log posted. I realized that It keeps saying that I need a flag of new activity, even when I'm using it

Comment: Still without solution. No suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are running this in `onStart()`, which means that `this.getBaseContext()` will return `null` as a Context is not created until `onCreate()`.

Either use:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Lista.class);
```

or move the code into `onCreate()`.

Comment: OnCreate is before onStart in Android Activity Lifecycle so this answer is not valid!